# Using AccessibleObjectFromWindow in python on Microsoft Word instance

Tags: python, com, ms-word

I am trying to manipulate a particular already-open, unsaved (so no path) Word document (*.doc) with python.  The manipulations work great if only one Word instance is open, however multiple instances create some difficulty, reference the SO question [Word VBA and Multiple Word Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633551/word-vba-and-multiple-word-instances).

I have found some references on dealing with this in C# ([How to access Microsoft Word existing instance using late binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203968/how-to-access-microsoft-word-existing-instance-using-late-binding?lq=1)) and VB.NET ([Multiple Instances of Applications](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/-net-office-automation/313079-multiple-instances-applications.html#post1351363)) and have managed to translate them to python to a point.  Here's where I am now:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import win32gui
#GUID class from http://svn.python.org/projects/ctypes/tags/release_0_2/ctypes/comtypes/GUID.py
from GUID import GUID
from ctypes import oledll
from ctypes import byref
from comtypes import POINTER
from comtypes.automation import IDispatch

#Use win32 functions to get the handle of the accessible window
#of the desired Word instance.  Specific code not relevant here, 
#but I'll end up with an integer such as:
hwnd = 2492046

OBJID_NATIVEOM = 0xffffff0
IID_IDispatch = byref(GUID("{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"))
p = POINTER(IDispatch)()
oledll.oleacc.AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnd, OBJID_NATIVEOM, IID_IDispatch, p)
```

When run, this returns the error message:

```
  File "wordtest.py", line 55, in <module>
    oledll.oleacc.AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnd, OBJID_NATIVEOM, IID_IDispatch, p)
  File "_ctypes/callproc.c", line 945, in GetResult
WindowsError: [Error -2147024809] The parameter is incorrect
```

Any assistance in fixing this error would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some searching through the GitHub code of NVDA (Non-Visual Desktop Access) showed that the value I was using for OBJID_NATIVEOM was incorrect, I needed to wrap the pointer in a byref(), and there was an easier way to get the GUID of IDispatch:

```
#Part of the pywin32 package that must be installed with the pywin32
#installer:
import win32gui

from ctypes import oledll
from ctypes import byref

#installed by easy_install comtypes
from comtypes import POINTER
from comtypes.automation import IDispatch
import comtypes.client.dynamic as comDy

#Handle integer hwnds[0] from code at 
#http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33901597/getting-last-opened-ms-word-document-object

OBJID_NATIVEOM = -16
p = POINTER(IDispatch)()
oledll.oleacc.AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnds[0], OBJID_NATIVEOM,
    byref(IDispatch._iid_), byref(p))

window = comDy.Dispatch(p)
word = window.application
cert = word.Documents(1)
```