# VBA - how to count open Word documents from multiple instances

Tags: vba, ms-word, multiple-instances

With 3 Word documents opened in separate instances the Documents count will return 1 instead of 3.

```
Word.Application.Documents.Count
```

Is it possible to loop through all instances and count/address the documents?

Cor

Comment: Why do you have multiple Word application instances? How are the 3 word documents being opened into 3 separate instances?

Comment: For multiple instances you will likely need to look into Windows API calls to find each instance and check whatever from there. [Windows API Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-api-list)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30363748/having-multiple-excel-instances-launched-how-can-i-get-the-application-object-f has what you need for this

Comment: Thx! I'm going to try to apply that to Word.
@Raymond: that's the default behaviour when you select multiple files and press enter. If you open any document after that it will be added to the last opened instance.
A big problem with many other forum topics is that the files aren't opened by the VBA script itself but earlier by a user, so I can't list the instance objects in advance.
I guess this will work though

Comment: Hi all, the given links and the topic this is duplicated to did give the correct answer. I did find it difficult to interpret with the VBA knowledge I had back then, but the following answer made it clear to me how to build up the code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54374826/how-to-iterate-over-multiple-word-instances-with-accessibleobjectfromwindow